# How to evaluate loss only on elements satisfying a condition pytorch

Tags: pytorch, regression, loss-function

I'm working on a regression problem in pytorch. I get good results on my evaluation set, but I want to make sure it's not because I have many small elements and less large ones. Therefore, I would like to check whether I get similar loss for the large elements (eg. elements > 0.01). I use mse loss.

Can anyone pls suggest a way of doing so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can zero-out loss for smaller elements (assuming size of elements is based on your regression target), you can implement your own loss function like this:

```
import torch


class CustomMSE:
    def __init__(self, threshold=0.01, reduction=torch.mean):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.reduction = reduction

    def __call__(self, output, target):
        # Do not reduce, so you get per-element loss
        loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(output, target, reduction="none")
        loss[target < self.threshold] = 0
        return self.reduction(loss)

criterion = CustomMSE()
```

You can use it just like `torch.nn.MSELoss`, this should give you an overall idea.